# Colocar como sub menu los sub items de la API a la cual se llama

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

Tengo una API (https://simplebackend-dmwjvq7ka.now.sh/menu) y con la cual debo crear un Navbar con los datos de la misma. Ya hice el llamado y me traje los menu principales; pero resulta que el id:0 tiene unos sub item los cuales debería ir debajo de la palabra o menu "Jeans". es decir:

- jeans>
- > Holgados
- > Apretados

este sub menu se debe mostrar al momento de hacer hover sobre jeans.

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

El pequeño ejercicio esta en react dejo el enlace al código:
https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-api-m2q9y

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

A ver, una posible opción sería la de mostrar el componente 'a' cuando `subItems` esté vació y una lista cuando éste tenga elementos.

En el render tendríamos algo así:

```js
<nav className="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      {menuData.map(cv => (
        <div
          key={cv.id}
          className="wrapper"
          onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(`Se hizo clic al menú ${cv.title}`);
          }}
        >
          <a href="true">{cv.title}</a>
          {cv.subItems && cv.subItems.length > 0 && (
            <>
              {cv.subItems.map(st => (
                <a key={st.id} href="true">
                  {st.title}
                </a>
              ))}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </nav>
```

No obstante he añadido los cambios en el ejemplo que mostrabas.
https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-api-9vqqu?file=/src/components/Navbar.jsx:439-1094

Answer (score 1):

Mi consejo es que separes la lógica de cada elemento en un componente distinto. En este caso yo haría un componente `Navbar` (como tienes) y otro para cada componente de ese `Navbar` (`NavbarItem`). Dentro de ese componente controlarías el estado para ver si tus `subItems` serían visibles o no. Además, podrías añadir otro componente que fuera cada `subItem` individual en caso de que quisieras controlar estados dentro de ellos.

Te dejo [aquí](https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-api-6wi2d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) el ejemplo de cómo lo he hecho yo (está sin estilos pero la funcionalidad básica sería algo así).